# Mysql Count with Inner join of two tables, Average Join

Tags: mysql, join, count

Im eager to join two tables but can´t seem to get it right, the structure look like this.

**Table1 (members)**
[UserLogin | Name ]

**Table 2 (articles)**
[ArtID | Writer | Content]
Article.writer is pointing to Members.UserLogin

I want to display with as little code as possible, the whole list of registered UserLogins but also a count of how many articles they might have written, or if they have´nt written any they should still be on the list as well.

What I would like:
[UserLogin | Name | ArticlesWritten]

What I´ve got so far is:

```
SELECT UserLogin, Name, Writer, count(*)
FROM Article
INNER JOIN Members on Writer=UserLogin
GROUP BY UserLogin;
```

or

```
SELECT UserLogin, Name, count(Writer)
FROM Article
LEFT JOIN Members ON UserLogin = Writer
GROUP BY 1;
```

Both of them lists everything fine in mysql, but none of them contains the UserLogins and Names of those who never has written any article. Can you guys point me in the right direction. I Understand the problem with my queries, but I have no idea on how to solve it.

I´ve found similar problems on this forum, but I have´nt got to any solution from them. Might be a language barriere or just a plain lack of basic mysql-knowledge.

Comment: `"foreign key is "Name" which is pointing to "Writer"` -- isn't it `Article.writer` is pointing to `Members.UserLogin` in which table `Article` is dependent on table `Members`?

Comment: Yes thats what i mean, will edit. sorry...

Answer (score 20):

You can use subquery

```
SELECT m.UserLogin, 
       m.Name, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM Articles 
         WHERE Writer = m.UserLogin) ArticlesWritten
  FROM Members m
```

Sample output:

```
| USERLOGIN |  NAME | ARTICLESWRITTEN |
---------------------------------------
|     user1 |  Jhon |               2 |
|     user2 | Helen |               0 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69281/1)**

Comment: `Writer = m.Name` here `m.UserLogin` would come

Comment: @DevalShah OP's exact words *...foreign key is "Name" which is pointing to "Writer"...*

Comment: It´s my fault... From the beginning.

Answer (score 9):

just use `LEFT JOIN` an interchange the table names,

```
SELECT UserLogin, Name, count(Writer)
FROM   Members 
       LEFT JOIN Article on Writer = UserLogin
GROUP  BY UserLogin, Name
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

in your question you state, *"foreign key is "Name" which is pointing to "Writer"*, isn't it `writer is pointing to UserLogin` in which table `Article` is dependent on table `Members`?

Comment: I really like your answer, concise and you gave me some great reading. Works like a charm, and it´s good you understood my intention although the info had a mistake in it... Many thanks! Hopefully someone more will learn from it while making article/member queries.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  m.UserLogin,
  m.Name,
  (SELECT
     COUNT(a.ArtID)
   FROM Article a
   WHERE a.Writer = m.UserLogin) AS ArticlesWritten
FROM Members m
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT m.UserLogin,m.Name,COUNT(a.ArtID) FROM Members m LEFT JOIN Article a ON a.Writer=m.Name GROUP BY m.Name;
```